# How do i resolve Dependency Warning's in android Studio?

Tags: android, dependencies, warnings, build.gradle

I'm new to android app development

When i clean and build app in android studio,Gradle Build Shows these warnings.

Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

Warning:Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305'. Resolved versions for app (1.3.9) and test app (2.0.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.

How to resolve these warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Way 1:**

You need to use the following in `build.gradle`

```
android{
   useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

If you use latest version of android SDK.

**Way 2:**

Use `HttpURLConnection` class instead of `HTTPClient. HttpURLConnection` is more efficient than HTTPClient.